# Parsing JSON with Logstash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm having problems to parse this json into elasticsearch with logstash:

```
{
  "type1": {}, 
  "type2": {
    "id": {
      "param1": value1, 
      "param2": value2, 
      "param4": value3, 
      "param4": value4, 
      "param5": value5
    }
  }, 
  "type3": {}
}
```

I'm using this logstash config:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      data => "http://blablah/json_data"
    }
    request_timeout => 10
    interval => 15
    codec => "json"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

I want to map the "type" to the elastic "_type" value, and the "id" to the elastic "_id" value, but cant achieve that.

I've read tons of doc about filters and grok and my head is about to explode.

Any help is really apreciated :)

EDIT: Expected output

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-16.07.21",
  "_type": "type2",
  "_id": "id",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": {
      "param1": value1,
      "param2": value2,
      "param3": value3,
      "param4": value4,
      "param5": value5
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-07-21T16:12:29.716Z"
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "param3": "value3",
    "param4": "value4",
    "param5": "value5"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1469117549716
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: could you use a json filter for that https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Comment: @WaldemarNeto As there is already a json codec in the input to parse the json, the json filter is useless here

Comment: Could you add an example of the expected result corresponding to the json input? And what you are getting with the current configuration.

Comment: @baudsp edited with the expected output :)